# BlobClient - What is the recommended way to check if my upload was successfull?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

The Azure blob client's [Upload method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-upload(system-binarydata)) returns a `Response<BlobContentInfo>`.

If the upload throws an exception, than something is wrong, that's clear.
Failure cases, like bad connection string or no internet connection does throw an exception. And it retries by default.

But if I do get a Response back, can still something be wrong?

On the [BlobContentInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobcontentinfo?view=azure-dotnet) I see no indicator of any error.

The Response has a [GetRawResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response-1.getrawresponse?view=azure-dotnet#azure-response-1-getrawresponse) method, and there is a `IsError` bool flag on that, and a `Status` for HTTP status code. But no specific description if something goes wrong.

Maybe check for `IsError`, and try to log the response, if it's true, and assume it did work, if there is no error. And check the `ContentHash` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I do get a Response back, can still something be wrong?

No. It would mean what you were trying to upload got uploaded successfully.

If your upload fails, the method will raise an exception of type [`RequestFailedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception?view=azure-dotnet).